# Running Python Script from different working directory

Tags: python, subprocess

I have this program Namechange.py which changes names from files (always cuts some useless end). Everything works fine, but I use this file a lot in a lot of different directories, which is bothersome when I want to change something. What I'm searching for is a python script which
let's me execute this script in a directory I choose.

My first idea was that I run another script which copies Namechange.py 
in the desired directory and then executes it there and deletes it after
everythings finished. The copying part works. 
Till now I tried using symlink ( it just executed the script in the working directory :D) as well as the subprocess module, which says there is no such directory when I use:

> subprocess.call(["cd", newpath])

newpath is the absolute path to the directory I want to use the script.

with error OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

If somebody has a elegant way to achieve this I would be glad.

Thanks and goodbye

Comment: What environment are you running in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the beginning of your script

```
import os
os.chdir("/dir/to/goto/before/running/the/script")

# rest of the logic goes here
```

assuming your script is run like this

./my_script dir/to/work/on

then you can do

```
import os
import sys
os.chdir(sys.argv[1])

# rest of the logic goes here
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Things you use from anywhere should be reachable from anywhere.

That's where the system's `PATH` environment variable comes in.

You should either move your script to a directory in the `PATH`, or extend the `PATH` with the location of your script.

Note:
make sure the script works location-independently: use `sys.path` extensively, try to use `sys.path.join(base, sub)` where possible etc...

Comment: thanks for you answer, brought me to think about the PATH variable in linux  systems. What I don't understand is what the join(base, sub) function does.

Comment: PATH is on windows, too.  It's actually meant to solve the problem you described.

Comment: the `path.join(...)` is especially useful when making scripts that have to work on different platforms (i.e. takes care of forward slash/backward slash/dot/...).  Probably not your problem, though.